# trying to upgrade from Ruby 1.9 to 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

trying to upgrade from Ruby 1.9 to 2.0 on mac 10.7.5

entered the following commands

```
rvm get stable
rvm install 2.0.0 \
      --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr \
      --verify-downloads 1
```

starts installing and configuring then get error

```
 Error running '__rvm_make -j 1',
please read /usr/local/rvm/log/1383664449_ruby-2.0.0-p247/make.log  (how do i find this file!=)
```

Comment: you can access the log file from command line:`vi /usr/local/rvm/log/1383664449_ruby-2.0.0-p247/make.log` Feel free to replace 'vi' by an editor of your choosing

Comment: -bash: /usr/local/rvm/log/1383664449_ruby-2.0.0-p247/make.log: Permission denied

Comment: if you have typed `vi /usr/local/rvm/log/1383664449_ruby-2.0.0-p247/make.log` and are getting permission denied, this is strange. as long as you are just reading the file, you can try the same, but with sudo: `sudo vi /usr/local/rvm/log/1383664449_ruby-2.0.0-p247/make.log`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest following this tutorial: [Tutorial for RVM](http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion)

I had this issue a while ago, and using sudo completely screwed up the permissions on my computer.  You do not want to be using sudo for every command that you generate.  Make sure that your RVM and RUby 2.0.0 is installed on your system without using sudo.

Answer (score -1):

try `sudo rvm install 2.0.0`. this will get you through. If you have installed `rvm` as a super user, you always need to use `sudo`

Comment: Do not use sudo for single user installs, especially if you are not experienced with system internals. From (https://rvm.io/rvm/install) "Using this type of installation without knowledge how umask works is a big security risk"

Comment: if your `rvm` is installed as a `super user` you need to use `sudo`

Comment: if your rvm is installed with sudo for a single user install, it is  better to uninstall it and install again properly (without sudo) instead of perpetuating an error

Comment: @neil- did you found your solution??

Comment: i managed to look at the file[2013-11-05 15:14:37] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247
command(3): __rvm_make -j 1
 CC = gcc-4.2
 LD = ld
 LDSHARED = gcc-4.2 -dynamiclib
 CFLAGS = -O3 -I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -fno-common -pipe 
 XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
 CPPFLAGS = -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin11.4.2 -I./include -I.

Comment: dude if that worked mark this as an answer so that others will not mislead with `-1` marked for this answer

Comment: sure using `sudo` 'worked', in the same sense as opening a house door with a crowbar and a blowtorch would 'work'. But it is still not the right tool for the job and has **serious security implications** as I mentioned in my first comment. It is better to look for the key instead of smashing your way in.

Comment: @kostja could you please make me aware of what `serious security implications` will be hampred??

Comment: you do not have to take my word for it. Perhaps you should take explicit warnings by the makers of RVM themselves against using `sudo` [for single-user rvm installations](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) as well as [for gem installation](https://rvm.io/support/faq#do-i-need-to-use-sudo-with-gems) seriously. So the question is rather - what reasoning do you have to simply ignore these warnings?

Comment: where in the question has @Neil mentioned that the RVM is installed for single user, I dont find any hard and fast reason to Downvote the answer though, if you are not sure you should make an edit to the answer or should leave a comment for more clarification brother..